# Run command on detached screen session attached to /dev/ttyUSB instance

Tags: bash, usb, gnu-screen, tty

I've been manually sending AT commands to a cellular modem connected over USB using `screen` by starting the session like so: `screen /dev/ttyUSB0`. I'd like to automate the commands I send to the device in a bash script, but have been unsuccessful thus far. Here's what I've tried:

1. redirecting output of a command to the tty instance: `echo 'AT COMMAND' > /dev/ttyUSB0`
2. sending a command to a detached screen session: `screen -d -m 'AT COMMAND' /dev/ttyUSB0`
3. using stty to configure the serial port and send a command:

   - `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 raw -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke`
   - `echo -e -n 'command_here\r'  > /dev/ttyUSB0`

I'm open to using other scripting languages and the libraries they provide (such as the `pyserial` library for Python), but I prefer Unix commands that I can use directly without downloading additional packages.